# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String okhttp3.ResponseBody.string()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, node.js, nullpointerexception, retrofit

Hi im using a node js server and retrofit

the login service is working perfectly and i've tested it on postman
i was sending only a message from my server but when i tried to send User model like this : [image]
this problem of nullpointer exception arrives and it points on this line [image]

i want to get the User to pass to the next interface which is profile  and display some data
the login api was working perfectly until i did this change :[image]

I was only displaying "message":"auth successful" and it was working

Comment: Where have you defined the Response body? Show the Object of ResponseBody class

Comment: I did not define it

Answer (score 0):

Your model class is not as per your response. I can see, you are adding user as object, but in response you are getting user as a list.

Replace

```
private User user
```

with

```
private List<User> user
```

and update respective methods too.

also add a check as below

```
 if(response.body() != null)
    String response = response.body().toSting()
```

Comment: You are trying to get body in error section too. Have you tried to add same check in that case or not?

Comment: i did not understand what should i add can you explain please ?

Comment: Use null check in else case too

Comment: i did that too but its not working sir please can you check my new post i followed Sarah's instructions which is building a new responsebody class  can you check please my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65109696/app-crash-in-login-using-retrofit-and-a-node-js-server

Comment: You json response is not matching with your model class. Try to generate data class for the exact json what are you getting in response.

Comment: thats what i did i followed the json response in my loginresponse model class is there any mistake ?

Comment: yes, your model class is not correct. Just share the json rather than sharing photo of response.

Comment: i just edited the post can you check what is wrong please ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65109696/app-crash-in-login-using-retrofit-and-a-node-js-server

Comment: You are still adding images.

Comment: I have updated the answer, Please have a look.

Comment: OMG thanks bro the authentification is successful when i enter correct data
but when i enter a user that is not created in database the app still crashes and it show me this error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.example.miniprojet.Models.LoginResponse.isError()' on a null object reference
        at

Comment: For nullpointer exception you need to check the reaponse in case of errors. What is json in case of error and how you are accessing it.

Comment: And also Kindly Upvote and accept answer if it worked for you.